# Specify credentials for HTTP authentication when using unparsed-text in XSLT 2.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, saxon

I discovered you can get text files through HTTP using the `unparsed-text` function in XSLT 2.0. Works great, but a file I need to get requires basic HTTP authentication. Tried the following, but that didn't seem to make any difference.

```
<variable name="text" select="unparsed-text('http://test:1234@localhost/file.txt')" />
```

Is there a way I can specify credentials to use when using this `unparsed-text` function?

Comment: I really not undertand... But try the basic way,  `<xsl:variable name="text">http://test:1234@localhost/file.txt</xsl:variable>`

Comment: @PeterKrauss If the example code had worked (which it does if I turn off basic authentication), then `$text` would contain the contents of the file located at `http://localhost/file.txt`. Not the URI, but the contents of the actual file. My problem is that when I turn on basic authentication (which the actual server I'm supposed to call uses), the parser crashes because of the 401 response it gets. I.e. I need to authenticate somehow. Simply adding it to the URL like in my example didn't work. So wondering if there is another way, or if I'm basically blocked here...

Comment: You might want to investigate whether using http://expath.org/modules/http-client/ and http://expath.org/spec/http-client#d2e430 is an option for you.

Comment: Ops, sorry, yes (!), `unparsed-text()` is a XSLT2 function... Well, I use XSLT only in a (strict) [MVC context](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), so this kind of function (that gets external data) is provided by the Model or the Controler... So, perhaps, registering your Java  function (get_unparsed_text) by [ExtensionFunctionDefinition](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/saxon6.5/extensibility.html), is a more direct approach, that not overwhelm your XSLT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of research, I am quite confident it can only be done with an extension function to handle HTTP requests appropriately. In other words, using `unparsed-text()` alone will not get you anywhere, as you have noticed.

It seems to me that the [extension functions written by Florent Georges](http://fgeorges.org/xslt/saxon-ext/) would meet your needs. The code below is not my own, I have adapted it from an example on the website.

It is an example for a delete request, with basic authentication in place. This works both for `document()` and `unparsed-text()`.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:ex="java:org.fgeorges.xslt.Exslt2"
                exclude-result-prefixes="ex"
                version="2.0">

   <!-- Parameters: the user (default to admin), the password
        (required) and the document to delete. -->
   <xsl:param name="user" select="'test'"/>
   <xsl:param name="pwd" required="yes"/>
   <xsl:param name="doc" select="'/file.txt'"/>

   <!-- The URI to be resolved -->
   <xsl:variable name="uri" select="
       'http://localhost'"/>

   <!-- The HTTP request -->
   <xsl:variable name="request">
      <http-request
          method="delete"
          user="{ $user }"
          password="{ $pwd }"/>
   </xsl:variable>

   <!-- The main template -->
   <xsl:template match="/" name="initial">
      <xsl:variable name="res" select="
          ex:http-send($request, concat($uri, $doc))"/>
     <!--Further processing-->
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am sure whether those extensions can still be used with recent versions of Saxon. Perhaps you should use the [EXPath HTTP Client](http://expath.org/modules/http-client/samples) instead - which is very similar to the extension described above.

Comment: Yep, that is what I have concluded with as well. Either get the content some other way and pass it in as a parameter, or use an extension function. Seeing as Florent Georges himself has a warning on his page saying we should use the [EXPath HTTP Client](http://www.expath.org/modules/http-client/) instead, I would thing that is the best option :)

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to using extension functions, with Saxon you can register an UnparsedTextURIResolver to look after the URI dereferencing.

Comment: Interesting idea. Would do that if I had easier access to Saxon itself, but it's a component hidden deep inside a commercial ESB product :p